# What is the preferred way to read data from kernel space devices into user space processes?

Tags: kernel, devices

I am currently querying my sensors by first opening a file descriptor of the device node, calling read() on it and closing the file descriptor again. For dynamic sensor data I would repeat this procedure endlessly in a loop.

I wonder if there is a more economical way to mirror or symlink data, that already lies in a file-like structure in the device tree instead of creating a copy of this data that is already present in memory.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a custom filesystem, and expose your data by mounting that. Perhaps a clean solution is a user-space filesystem, or some userspace-only option like the ancient `mtools(1)` to read/write FAT filesystems.

In any case, it strongly depends on the use of said data. Unless performance is truly critical, a pure userland solution is probably easiest to build and most flexible/future proof. Futzing around in the kernel's space is *guaranteed* to leave you high and dry very soon by the furious development rate, unless you manage to get your stuff included in the official kernel, or adhere strictly to only using officially exported interfaces in your modules.

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping for a way to map a variable to the device node data, instead of reading it over and over. I don’t worry about the path. All my devices are in the mainline kernel and have fixed addresses there.